# How to call a function in a certain frequency, C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner to C++, trying to improve my skills by working on a project.
I am trying to have my program call a certain function 100 times a second for 30 seconds.
I thought that this would be a common, well documented problem but so far I did not manage to find a solution.
Could anyone provide me with an implementation example or point me towards one?

Notes: my program is intended to be single-threaded and to use only the standard library.

Comment: I saw this question with the same title and all, few days ago. But can't find the that dupe right now. Maybe it got closed and deleted.

Comment: Look up your OS documentation.  Use a timer that can call your function when the timer elapses.  The timer capability and interface depends on the OS, which you didn't specify.

Comment: If you just want to use the standard library, you'll probably want to take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono .

Comment: Side note: It's always a good idea to show what research you've done so that answers can avoid repeating work you have already done and rejected or show you how to apply  the research you have done. Plus you should never discount the social importance of showing your work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::this_thread::sleep_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until) and calculate the end time of the sleep according to desired frequency:

```
void f()
{
    static int counter = 0;
    std::cout << counter << '\n';
    ++counter;
}

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    using Clock = std::chrono::steady_clock;


    constexpr auto period = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(1s) / 100; // conversion to ms needed to prevent truncation in integral division

    constexpr auto repetitions = 30s / period;

    auto const start = Clock::now();

    for (std::remove_const_t<decltype(repetitions)> i = 1; i <= repetitions; ++i)
    {
        f();
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(start + period * i);
    }
}
```

Note that this code will not work, if `f()` takes more than 10ms to complete.

**Note:** The exact duration of the `sleep_until` calls may be off, but the fact that the sleep duration is calculated based on the current time by `sleep_until` should result in any errors being kept to a minimum.

Comment: Might want to mention that this is not perfectly accurate.

Comment: @JHBonarius You're right, answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

There are two reasons you couldn't find a trivial answer:

1. This statement "I am trying to have my program call a certain function 100 times a second for 30 seconds"  is not well-defined.
2. Timing and scheduling is a very complication problem.

In a practical sense, if you just want something to run approximately 100 times a second for 30 seconds, assuming the function doesn't take long to run, you can say something like:

```
for (int i=0;i<3000;i++) {
    do_something();
    this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10)); 
}
```

This is an approximate solution.

Problems with this solution:

- If do_something() takes longer than around 0.01 milliseconds your timing will eventually be way off.
- Most operating systems do not have very accurate sleep timing.  There is no guarantee that asking to sleep for 10 milliseconds will wait for exactly 10 milliseconds.  It will usually be approximately accurate.

Comment: "Timing and scheduling is a very complication problem." Specifically on a non-realtime system/platform. On dedicated hardware/ bare metal applications it is achievable

Comment: Large parts of this answer assume that it's impossible to compensate for durations of `do_something` and `sleep_for`. This is simply incorrect, since you can recalculate the time to sleep based on the time the previous iterations took, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72914607/2991525), it should even be working, if the duration of `do_something` is 9ms.

Answer (score 0):

You can't time it perfectly, but you can try like this:

```cpp
using std::chrono::steady_clock;
using namespace std::this_thread;

auto running{ true };

auto frameTime{ std::chrono::duration_cast<steady_clock::duration>(std::chrono::duration<float>{1.0F / 100.0F}) }

auto delta{ steady_clock::duration::zero() };

while (running) {
    auto t0{ steady_clock::now() };
    while (delta >= frameTime) {
        call_your_function(frameTime);
        delta -= frameTime;
    }

    if (const auto dt{ delta + steady_clock::now() - t0 }; dt < frameTime) {
        sleep_for(frameTime - dt);
        delta += steady_clock::now() - t0;
    }
    else {
        delta += dt;
    }
}
```